# Problems with the install of Ubuntu on a windows machine

Tags: system-installation

I currently run Windows XP but the machine is one I built and will run a 64 bit OS.

I downloaded the ISO file from the download site burnt a bootable DVD with the ISO. The machine boots up just fine then runs a file check - this is also fine.

After waiting for the DVD to stop, the screen freezes with a picture of a large cat. Repeat burn with different burn software, three times - same result.

Any ideas??

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; what product you're talking about (Desktop? Server? or another product, let alone what release).  Your provided details do not exclude user-error issues due to bad choice for your hardware.

Comment: "*Picture of a large cat" suggests Ubuntu Desktop 20.04, but it's much better if you are explicit in your question rather than letting us guess.

Comment: My old laptop from 2006 that was XP, cannot now run Ubuntu. I used to install Ubuntu & it was very slow. Then installed a different desktop. Now I cannot install Ubuntu, but was able to install Kubuntu, which is not really a lightweight flavor but lighter than Ubuntu. Light weight flavors for older systems:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

Comment: I have desktops from 2006 that will happily run modern Ubuntu (the lighter *flavors* make more sense), but I've also laptops from as late as 2007 that won't run 20.04 & later as x86/i386 only (not *amd64*). I'd compare you *unstated* release with what is appropriate with your hardware (you gave no details), and take into account what video hardware you're using (eg. are you using nvidia? did you try using *safe graphics* etc as per your *unstated* release & ISO used).  I'd switch to a text terminal (if *desktop* ISO) and explore there for clues; but we don't know what you're using

Comment: Many thanks old fred for your helpful comments and advice I have already changed to Kubuntu and it installed with no trouble. the least said about the other two responses the better.